# Always coming Column Stored index scan instead of Seek

Tags: sql-server-2014, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I have created a column stored index(Clustered/Non-Clustered) on a table. But when i use that table in my query always Column Store Index scan is coming in the Execution Plan. Why Column-Store Index seek is not coming ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a columnstore index seek, it is always a scan. Albeit sometimes segment elimination can avoid the need to read the whole thing.